# Solr: How to dynamically elevate limited number of documents? Has QueryElevationComponent to be modified?

Tags: java, solr, lucene, elevation

my requirement is to elevate a **limited number** of (e.g. five) documents for a user request.

What I've got is a single **document field** which stores a numerical value similar to a boosting value which represents an **elevator ranking value**.

So a user query would return 5 documents with the highest elevator ranking value and the remaining documents to fill a page in regular order.

How to do that?

The `QueryElevationComponent` does only allow **static** query definitions. Boosting does not allow to boost a **limited number** of documents for the special elevator ranking field.

Do I have to write a modified QueryElevationComponent? If yes, are there good **examples** how to do that?

Or does **another approach** exists, I didnt catched up?

Thank you for any hints or ideas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution using two separate requests.

First boost documents by that score field. Use pagination to limit the result. Take the unique document ids from the result page and boost these ones explicitly within a new request.

Comment: No. You just need to use an ExternalFileField to achieve what you just did using two requests. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6015879/external-file-field-in-apache-solr/17331497#17331497

Answer (score 1):

I would have one of these two approaches:

- Either use an [**function query**](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery) to boost on the elevator ranking field.
- Or use [**index time boosting**](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateXmlMessages#Optional_attributes_on_.22doc.22) to boost the documents that need editorial boosting.

Both these methods can produce unpredictable results (since the relevance model in Solr is very complex). However with the function query you are able to fine tune a bit more.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. How can I limit the number of boosted documents with that approaches?