# request counting for documents in apache solr

Tags: mysql, solr

I have a simple website that is using apache solr for request of specific documents. Now I have to count the total number of request for each document served. I know that I have to use some database for this purpose. But I do not know how to update documents in database on fly i.e. when documents are served. I have used DIH to import documents from mysql to solr. 
How do I do it.

Answer (score 2):

please be more specific about your use-case.

I will answer for this question:
What should I do to count all delivered documents and use the count to change the ranking of my documents?

1. Count per document(-ID)

If you really can not do this inside your application than generate your own [SearchComponent](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/RequestHandlers+and+SearchComponents+in+SolrConfig#RequestHandlersandSearchComponentsinSolrConfig-SearchComponents) to collect the document-Ids from the result-DocSet. Use [StatsComponent](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/tags/lucene_solr_5_4_0/solr/core/src/java/org/apache/solr/handler/component/StatsComponent.java) as starting point.

2. Use a dynamic count per document for ranking

Updating a solr-document is expensive. So use [ExternalFileField](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Working+with+External+Files+and+Processes): 
[External File Field in Apache Solr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6015879/external-file-field-in-apache-solr)

Comment: Can you elaborate case 1 or 2. ?

Comment: Your perception is correct that I have to change ranking of documents

Comment: I have configured external file field successfully. But Solr is not going to update ids info in the file that is viewed

Comment: Hi Shafiq, this sounds like this question: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Working+with+External+Files+and+Processes?focusedCommentId=61326780#comment-61326780

Answer (score 0):

You can use Schema browser to view frequency of search in solr.

[image: 1]

You can view on every field.

Histogram represents top searches and their frequency for terms.

[image]

But to update you need your own search component that updates count in database.