# How to update Apache solr external file field for each request

Tags: apache, solr

I have to use an [external file field](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Working+with+External+Files+and+Processes) to count documents visits in Apache Solr 4.10. I have configured it successfully. Now the problem is how to update this external file field when a document is served ?

Answer (score 1):

The Question is how to reload an external file field in solr.

There are two events where you could add a listener:
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Working+with+External+Files+and+Processes#WorkingwithExternalFilesandProcesses-ReloadinganExternalFile

The event newSearcher will be called after an (empty) commit:
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Working+with+External+Files+and+Processes#comment-61333533

Problem with a direct reload of such file would be, that the user does not expect a change of order while using pagination:

- https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Pagination+of+Results
- http://yonik.com/solr/paging-and-deep-paging/

Comment: My question was how count value for each document (that is served) is updated in external file.

Comment: As far as I know there is now implemented "write to external file" in solr. Please see my answer (point 1.)  to your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34715990/request-counting-for-documents-in-apache-solr